# Product of exponentials of matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-analysis, matrix-theory, matrix-exponential

Let $A$ and $B$ be commuting $n\times n$ positive definite complex matrices and let $C$,$D$ be other complex matrices.  I wish to think of $C,D$ as small and $A,B$ as any size.

Suppose we are looking for a function $f(C,D)$ such that
$$ e^{A+C} e^{B+D} = e^{A+B+f(C,D)}$$

I would have thought that one can find a neighbourhood $U$ around the zero matrix such that one can define $f(C,D)$ for $C,D\in U$, and even probably arrange so that $f$ is analytic on $U\times U$ and $f(0,0)=0$.    Is this true?

Moreover, is it the case that one can find a neighbourhood $U$ that works no matter how large $A$ and $B$ are?

Any help/related ideas/references much appreciated.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula — The first terms are going to be $A+B+C+D+\frac{1}{2}[A+C,B+D]+\cdots$ so you can't expect $f(C,D)$ not to depend on $A$ and $B$.

Comment: I guess this is true if A, B are small.  Then the BCH formula will converge if C,D are also small, and how small depends on A,B.  But really I was thinking of the case that A,B are large in which case the BCH does not tell me anything at all about a possible f(C,D).  Does it?

Comment: What I'm saying is, if already for small (and commuting) $A,B$ the corrective term given by the BCH formula is not independent of $A$ and $B$, I don't see how you can hope for this to be true for all values (including large ones).  But maybe I misunderstood your question.